# Generating all subsets from a single set

Tags: c++

I was trying to understand the code to generate all the subsets from one set. Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Applies the mask to a set like {1, 2, ..., n} and prints it */
void printv(int mask[], int n) {
    int i;
    printf("{ ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (mask[i])
            printf("%d ", i + 1); /*i+1 is part of the subset*/
    printf("\\b }\\n");
}

/* Generates the next mask*/
int next(int mask[], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; (i < n) && mask[i]; ++i)
        mask[i] = 0;

    if (i < n) {
        mask[i] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = 3;

    int mask[16]; /* Guess what this is */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        mask[i] = 0;

    /* Print the first set */
    printv(mask, n);

    /* Print all the others */
    while (next(mask, n))
        printv(mask, n);

    return 0;
}
```

I am not understand the logic behind this line `for (i = 0; (i < n) && mask[i]; ++i)` inside the next function. How is the next mask being generated here?

Code and algorithm looked here:
http://compprog.wordpress.com/2007/10/10/generating-subsets/

Comment: Why don't you single-step this with a debugger, or add print statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is simply an implementation of [counting in binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Counting_in_binary). The basic idea is to change the least-significant (last) zero to a one, and change all the ones after it to zeroes. The "next" mask will be "one more" than the previous if interpreted as a binary number.

Because the array is arranged with the one's place first, it looks backwards from traditional numeric notation.

Instead of using an array of Boolean values, it could just as well use the bits in the binary representation of one number and the `++` operator.

```
int next(int &mask, int n) { // using C++ reference
    if ( mask == ( 1u << n ) - 1 ) return 0;
    ++ mask;
    return 1;
}

void printv(int mask, int n) {
    int i;
    printf("{ ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (mask & ( 1 << i ) )
            printf("%d ", i + 1); /*i+1 is part of the subset*/
    printf("\\b }\\n");
}
```

I've used a little C++ since you tagged the question as such, but the posted code is plain C.

Comment: Wat exactly is meant by `&& mask[i];` inside the `next` function's for loop ? And if you could also explain a bit about setting `mask[i]` to `1` if `i<n`?

Comment: `&& mask[i]` only continues setting bits to zero as long as they were originally one. It only sets the bit to one if `i<n` because you only want `n` bits of mask, any more bits would overflow the array.

Answer (score 2):

Last year I participated in the C language contest of the 6th ITAT competition where I solved the second problem by generating all comabinations with the help of a mask (though, it might not be an optimal solution to that problem.)

When you try to derive all the subsets of `{a,b,c}`, you do it this way:

1. You may or may not take the first element `a`.
2. May or may not take the 2nd element `b`.
3. Same for `c`.

So you wind up with a set of 3 take-or-not-take choices. This can be represented in binaries or boolean values: represent taking by `1`, and not taking by `0`.

You get the following eight masks: (by the order of `a,b,c`)

`000 100 010 110 001 101 011 111`

To generate the next mask of `110`:

1. element 0 is `1`. Switch it to `0`.
2. element 1 is `1`. Switch it to `0`.
3. element 2 is `0`. Switch it to `1`.
4. now you have `001` which is the next mask, which generates subset `{c}`.

`for (i = 0; (i < n) && mask[i]; ++i)` does exactly that.

1. start at element 0.
2. while (`i` doesn't exceed your mask length AND element i is `1`)
3. do the body code which flips i to `0`, and ++i (go to next element). goto 2 (check).

If the current mask is `111` (the last mask), the `next()` function simply returns `1` to indicate END.

(P.S. a non-zero integer always represents true.)

Answer (score 0):

The loop in questions starts at the beginning of the array and sets all 1s to 0s until a 0 in encountered. The next statement sets this 0 to a 1 (if possible). So what happens is: 0,0,0 -> 1,0,0 -> 0,1,0 -> 1,1,0 -> 0,0,1... I am not a hardcore C programmer but I think this could have been done easier by using a bit field and incrementing by 1 iteratively.

Comment: It would indeed be much easier as long as the number of elements is small enough to fit in a bit-field. Of course, when `n` is too large for that, it doesn't really matter because printing `2^n` subsets will take too long to bother.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; (i < n) && mask[i]; ++i)
```

1. for:
2. start at 0 and increment i by 1 each time
3. don't stop while i is less than n and the bit in the mask array at position i is set

it's straightforward really: 3 parts to a for statement: initial state; end condition; operation.

So if you can understand `for (i=0; i < 5; i++)` means start at 0 and increment i by 1 each time until it fails to be less than 5, you can understand the more complex for loop you asked about.

in this case, it's going through the loop looking for the first element of the mask that is not set, clearing each element as it goes, then it performs some other operation - namely if there was no mask bits set, and it reached the end of the array. Seems to me like a simple way of setting only one element of an array to 1, in sequence to get the result: 100, 010, 001