# What is the if statement in this code doing?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, combinations, operator-keyword, subset

This code iterates through an array getting subsets of the array items,
and pushes certain numbers to the `result` array. I just can't figure out how this `if` statement is filtering the numbers:

```
if( (mask & (1 << i)) !== 0){
   result.push(input[i]);
```

What does it mean exactly?

```
 (function(input){
    var result, mask, total = Math.pow(2, input.length);
        for(mask = 0; mask < total; mask++){ //O(2^n)
            result = [];
            i = input.length - 1; //O(n)
            debug(i)
            do{
                if( (mask & (1 << i)) !== 0){
                    result.push(input[i]);
                }
            }while(i--);
            debug(result);
        }
    })(['1','2','3']);
```

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: The net result of this function is to return an array with the original elements of the input array in reverse order.  Using bit-shift operations to track the elements is clever but not the most obvious way of doing this.  For large inputs, 2^N could lead to an overflow condition.  Where does this code come from?

Comment: http://www.coderbyte.com/CodingArea/Challenges/   -- so this is meant to be one method of generating combinations for summing up elements in an array ? @MarcAudet  I see that it is basically like binary counting over the array elements -- any other thoughts on a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `mask` variable seems to be like variable for selecting the subset of numbers from `input` array. Say size of input is `N` and mask is `N` bit number. So `input[i]` is selected only if `i` bit of `mask` is 1.

```
mask & (1 << i)) !== 0
```

This checks whether `i` bit of mask is 0 or not. If not 0 i.e.1, then `input[i]` is put in `result`.

Comment: Hi Shashwat, I'm still confused -- so if i<sup>th</sup> bit of mask is 1, how do we know that this input[i] should be part of the subset of the array ? ? ?

Comment: looks like this explains it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869866/generating-all-subsets-from-a-single-set